# how to register a upper filter driver to all printers class via .inf file (AddReg section)

Tags: driver, registry, inf

I have a [filter driver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_driver) (similar to following):

```
NTSTATUS MyFilterFunction (
    __in PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject,
    __in PIRP Irp
){
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    // do the filtering
    DbgPrint("Filtering with MyFilterFunction");
    return status;
}

NTSTATUS DriverEntry (
    __in PDRIVER_OBJECT  DriverObject,
    __in PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath
){
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CREATE] = MyFilterFunction
    return status;
}
```

I have made [this](http://pastie.org/1111849) inf file to attach the filter to printers-class drivers-stack.
**The problem is that when printing, the function DbgPrint does not output anything in DebugView, as if it's never called.**
Note that I use a network printer, not a local printer attached to the machine.